# How do I change all lines to be black color in seaborn.lineplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, linegraph

How do I change all lines to be black color in seaborn? I put "color = 'black' but it does not change from the default. I also want the whitegrid to be remanined in the graph but it disappears.

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date']).dt.date
sns.lineplot(data=data, x='date', y='count', hue='new_sentiment', style = 'new_sentiment', 
             color ='black')
sns.set_style("whitegrid", {
  "ytick.major.size": 0.1,
    "ytick.minor.size": 0.05,
   'grid.linestyle': 'solid',
    
 })
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04,1), loc="upper left")
plt.setp(plt.gca().xaxis.get_majorticklabels(),rotation=90)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%b-%Y'))
plt.xlim([datetime.date(2020, 1, 13), datetime.date(2021, 6, 15)])
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=24))
plt.savefig('04_clean_resentiment_count_2020_2021.tiff', dpi=300, format='tiff', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: You have `hue` attribute assigned to automatically color lines by `new_sentiment`. Remove it and all lines should be black.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the line graph in the official reference as an example, I set the line color to black. However, when it is just one color, it becomes difficult to identify the data. It may be better to use a single color shade for visualization.

[image]

import seaborn as sns

```
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
sns.set_style("whitegrid", {
  "ytick.major.size": 0.1,
    "ytick.minor.size": 0.05,
   'grid.linestyle': 'solid',
 })

g = sns.lineplot(data=flights, x="year", y="passengers", hue='month')
lines = g.get_lines()
[l.set_color('black') for l in lines]
g.legend()
```

[image]

```
sns.lineplot(data=flights, x="year", y="passengers", hue='month', palette=('Greys'))
```

[image]